# "remove type argument" while reading from excel file in java

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, mapreduce, iterator

I'm trying to read from an excel file in my java code (IDE is eclipse). My code is attached below. In  the line which Iterator is declared i face this error:
The type HTMLDocument.Iterator is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with argument . 
and offers me to "remove type argument."
I don't know what the problem is. I have downloaded necessary jar files and added them to my class path but it didn't help.

```
public static void readMapReduceTasksfromFile(String fileAddress) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    try
    {   

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("...directory...");

        HSSFWorkbook workBook = new HSSFWorkbook();

        HSSFSheet sheet = workBook.createSheet();


        Iterator <Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();//HERE


        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
           System.out.println("File Not Found");
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in an area of your code, which you have not posted: the import statements. You need to import `java.util.Iterator`. Instead it seems like you have imported`javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument.HTMLDocument.Iterator`.

Remove the erroneous import statement and use the "organize import" function in eclipse, this time make sure to choose `java.util.Iterator`.